# Adding sum formula between every space ranges by vba

Tags: excel, vba

I was trying to do an automation and i was stuck here, where i need to add sum formula dynamically in between the space ranges. I'm completely lost here for adding formula using VBA can anyone help me out.

[image]

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming what you want is if there is a blank in a cell, you want all of the other elements summed and the result placed in that blank. There are probably any number of ways to code this, but here is my attempt

```
Sub formulateSubtotals()
finalRow = Cells(Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
finalCol = Cells(1, Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
For j = 1 To finalCol
    For i = finalRow + 1 To 1 Step -1
        If IsEmpty(Cells(i, j)) Then
            If IsEmpty(Cells(i - 2, j)) Then
                firstRow = i - 1
                lastRow = firstRow
            Else
                lastRow = i - 1
                firstRow = Cells(i - 1, j).End(xlUp).Row
            End If
            Cells(i, j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(firstRow, j), Cells(lastRow, j)))
        End If
    Next i
Next j
End Sub
```

This also assumes that the sheet in question is entitled "Sheet1".

Comment: Your absolutely correct and  its working so cool.. Thank you so much i just lost my mind due to work pressure i really appreciate your help :)

Comment: It is my pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

**Without VBA**:

Say we have data in column **A** like:

[image]

and we want to calculate of sum of each of the blocks separated by a blank cell.  In **B2** enter:

```
=IF(A2<>"","",SUM($A$1:A2)-SUM($B$1:B1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

*If this is of no value, I will delete the answer.*

Comment: Wow that's really a cool formula! its working amazingly is there a way to get the answer in the same column A instead column B?

Comment: @Linga  For in-column sums, I would use Matt's approach.

Comment: Thank you for looking into this Gary :)